# Generic method for string and List<List(object)>

Tags: c#, generics

I'm new to C# generics and don't know a lot about it and still learning. I want to write a single generic method for these two methods. But since the method one receives List<List<> as parameter and method 2 receives string, so not sure how can i write a single generic method for these two:
Method 1

```
public static void WriteReports(string expectedDailyData, string actualDailyData, string fileName)
      {
         var baseline = FormatData(expectedDailyData);
         var actual = FormatData(actualDailyData);

         var baselineCSV = fileName + "Baseline";
         var actualCSV = fileName + "actual";
         var regressCSV = fileName + "RegressReport";
         WriteReport(baseline, baselineCSV); //this is generic method which handles List and List<List(object)>
         WriteReport(actual, actualCSV);

         try
         {
            WriteRegressionReport(baseline, actual, regressCSV);
         }
         catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
         {
            //catch
         }
      }
```

Method 2

```
   public static void WriteReports(List<List<object>> baseline, List<List<object>> actual, string fileName)
      {
         var baselineCSV = fileName + "Baseline";
         var actualCSV = fileName + "Actual";
         var regressCSV = fileName + "RegressReport";

         WriteReport(baseline, baselineCSV);
         WriteReport(actual, actualCSV);

         try
         {
            WriteRegressionReport(baseline, actual, regressCSV);
         }
     catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
     {
        // handle exception
     }
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might be less of a case for generics and more of a case for method overloading.

Comment: @Abion47 But basically both methods are doing the same thing and it's like redundant code so was thinking if there's a way to optimise the code

Comment: It's hard to give you some concrete code unless we know the type returned by `FormatData` - you've just left it as `var`. Ideally you should have posted a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You should not use generic methods here. Generics should be used when your method can work with *any* type (satisfying some constraints). If your method can only work with two types: `string` and `List<List<object>>`, then you should leave it as two overloads.

You *can* reduce the code duplication though. Observe that the body of the second method is "inside" the first method. You can replace everything after the second line of the first method with a call to the second method:

```
public static void WriteReports(string expectedDailyData, string actualDailyData, string fileName)
{
    var baseline = FormatData(expectedDailyData);
    var actual = FormatData(actualDailyData);
    WriteReports(baseline, actual, filename);
}
```

Comment: But the thing is in some cases I already receive formatted result but in some cases I have to format the result I got

Comment: @PeterJackson Yes, that's why you have two methods, right?

Comment: ahh right. Yes I got your point. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @PeterJackson If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: @PeterJackson, is there a particular reason why you do not mark answers as correct? I see you have quite a few questions and have not mark a single answer as correct. If you feel that an answer solved your question you have to select the grey tick mark to the left of the question so it becomes green, meaning the solution solved your question.